# Android opengl-es 3d file parser work is very slow

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a 3d file parser, but if I have a very big file (about 3 MB) the parsing wil be very slow. (55 seconds)

How can I speed it up?

I have a simple parser:

```
InputStream fileIn = resources.openRawResource(resourceID);
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIn));

while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
   StringTokenizer parts = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
   ...
```

etc.

**edit 1**

new code with AssetManager

```
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream fileIn = null;
    try {
        fileIn = assetManager.open(resourceID, AssetManager.ACCESS_RANDOM);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("err0", ""+e);
    }
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIn));
```

this is a little faster, with a 3 MB file, I get 38 seconds.

Thanks,
Leslie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is use the Android method profiler to determine which method in your algorithm is running the slowest. From there, you can try and make improvements to those methods (possibly by reusing objects, or removing unnecessary actions, etc). Finally, measure your code again to make sure your improvements actually worked as you expected them to. Unfortunately, there is no "silver bullet" to optimizing code.

If you have a lot of slow code in a single method, you could also use primitive time functions (like System.currentTimeMillis) to record how long certain tasks take to determine what is slowest.

Finally, just as a guess, I suspect that creating either very large strings OR large amounts of strings may be one source of slowness in your algorithm. Every time you read a single line, you are creating a new string. Then, you are creating even more strings by tokenizing them. All those objects eventually will be collected by the garbage collector which costs extra time. Maybe something you could do is read the raw bytes of the file into a re-used byte array and do your processing on that. If you know the character encoding of the file ahead of time (or maybe even the max line length), this might significantly reduce your execution time.

Comment: Hello Justin! Can you send me a sample how to use bytes as a readline string? Thanks, Leslie

Comment: It all depends on how the file is written. As an example though, lets say you knew the max length a line could be is 200 bytes. You could then read 200 bytes at a time from your file and process the data in the bytes looking for a newline character to terminate your line. Then you would keep whatever bytes were left over (lets say 20) and then read bytes to fill the buffer again (180 now). Keep doing this until your entire file is processed. Again, this is just a theory to why your parser is slow.

Comment: The main idea, is to avoid working with string data if you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would remove that parcer from you mobile app and place it as a preprocess tool that would write you 3d meshes to a flat binary format - unless your app is a 3d modelling tool! That way you can then easily load the data (and upload to gpu) with a single read routine.